# Remove or Replace Value in Array1 If Value Isn't in Array2 in Shell Script Without Looping?

Tags: arrays, bash, integer, pattern-matching, output

#### Edit:

I've change my definition of `allVals` to the somewhat cleaner/simpler:

```
allVals=( $( printf '%s\n' \
               $( printf '%s\n' \
                    {0..9}{0..9}{0,3,5,7} | \
                    sed -e 's#^0*##g' ) | \
               awk '$1>='"$valMin"' && $1<='"$valMax" ) \
            ${exptVals[@]} )
```

---

I have a short `BASH script` used to produce space separated configuration files for a secondary executable.  The scripted part is determining which values to print to column 1.

To accomplish this my script uses [brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) to create an array of integers with the following rules:

- Numbers are no more than `3` digits.
- Numbers are `integer` (no decimal).
- Products of `5` must be included in series.
- I need at least one evenly spaced point between the `[#][#]0` and `[#][#]5`  (i.e. a number ending in `3` or `7`, as appropriate).

I use `sed` to clean up the case where the second most significant digit is blank (I'll probably replace the ' ' with '0' and write a simpler equivalent by remove leading '0's when I get around to it...).

Anyhow, these are values I input into a second program to produce computed predictions for certain properties.  I also want to be sure to include numbers corresponding to certain experimental values I have... so I do that by creating an array of experimental values and then merging the two arrays together, sorting them and removing redundant values.

The script is given below (it was a oneliner -- I've edited it into script form for readability below):

```
#!/bin/bash
lineItem5=61
valMax=433
valMin=260
exptVals=( 257 261 265 269 273 277 281 285 289 293 297 \
           301 305 309 313 317 321 325 329 333 337 341 \
           345 349 353 357 361 365 369 373 377 381 385 \
           389 393 397 401 405 409 413 417 421 425 429 \
           433 )
allVals=( $( printf '%s\n' \
            $( printf '%s\n' {' ',{1..9}}{' ',{1..9}}{0,3,5,7} | \
                 sed -e 's# \([1-9]\) 0 [1-9] 3 [1-9] 5 [1-9] 7 # \100 \103 \105 \107 #g' ) | \
            awk '$1>='"$valMin"' && $1<='"$valMax" ) \
         ${exptVals[@]} )
sortVals=( $( printf '%s\n' ${allVals[@]} | sort -nr | uniq ) )
for ((t=0;t<${#sortVals[@]};t++)); do
  printf '%s\n' "${sortVals[t]}"'     -4000   -4000   200        '"${lineItem5}"'   -1.0'
done
unset exptVals allVals sortVals
```

It works, but I would like to cut down on the number of lines (which equate to evaluated points and hence computation cost) and improve the spacing of values (which improves my statistical accuracy as each point of outputted properties depends on the previous calculations).

Specifically I'd like to remove the value `##7` if the sequence `##7 ##8` is encountered, and likewise `##3` if the sequence `##2 ##3`... but only if the `##3` or `##7` value is not found in my list of experimental values.  Also I want to change `##3 ##4` to `##2 ##4` and `##6 ##7` to `##6 ##8` to improve the spacing -- but only if the `##3` or `##7` are not in the experimental sequence.

So far the best way to do this I can think of is doing something like

```
valStart=0
for ((e=0; e<${#exptVals[@]}; e++)); do
  for ((v=valStart; v<${#allT[@]}; v++)); do
     if [[ ${allVals[v]} -ge ${exptVals[$((e+1))]} ]]; then
       valStart=v
       break
    else
       #Do edits to list here... 
     fi
  done
done
```

The code isn't finished, but I think it would be moderately efficient as I don't have to loop through the second list entirely... just a small stretch of it (my experimental list is in order).

But I feel like there are easier ways to `delete 'Y' from 'X Y' if 'Y' is not in array $vals` or `change 'Y' to 'Z' for 'X Y' if 'Y' is not in array $vals`?

Is there a simple way to in a single expression using some sort of built in accomplish:

- `delete 'Y' from 'X Y' if 'Y' is not in array $vals`
- `change 'Y' to 'Z' for 'X Y' if 'Y' is not in array $vals`

...which does not involve looping through the values in bash-style loops (my brute-force method)?

Comment: In your script: Un assigned vars: `allVals[@]` and `sortVals[@]` I'll assume that `allT=(` is in fact `allVals=(` and that `t<${#sortT[@]}` should be in fact `t<${#sortVals[@]}` but I could be wrong. Could you please correct the script?

Comment: Correct.  I renamed the variables when I was writing the question, but neglected to change some variables' names leading to issues -- which I appreciate you bringing to my attention.  I've corrected all of them (I believe).

Comment: Why not do this in one go in awk? Your focus on no looping is silly IMHO.

Comment: I'm just putting my method for generating the input data and I'm not married to it... if you propose an awk alternative for that part I'd happily consider it... my question is open to any suggestions as to how to accomplish the editing and deletion rules on the final array... in fact I define my question to bias towards non bash constructs, as I already know how to do this more verbosely with bash constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you have makes calls to sed and awk to remove the spaces created by the brace expansion you used. A simpler brace expansion is:

```
$ echo {0..9}{0..9}{0,3,5,7}
```

The problem of the leading `0`s is easy to solve with `printf '%3.0f'`.
A shorter list (as an example) will be created with this:

```
$ printf '%3.0f ' {0..1}{0..9}{0,3,5,7}
  0   3   5   7  10  13  15  17  20  23  25  27  30  33  35  37  40  43  
 45  47  50  53  55  57  60  63  65  67  70  73  75  77  80  83  85  87  
 90  93  95  97 100 103 105 107 110 113 115 117 120 123 125 127 130 133  
135 137 140 143 145 147 150 153 155 157 160 163 165 167 170 173 175 177  
180 183 185 187 190 193 195 197
```

Once cleared this issue, we need to limit values between `valMin` and `valMax`.

Instead of calling an external awk to process a short list, a loop is better. With sorting (only called once) and printing, this script does about the same as yours with a lot less of external calls:

```
#!/bin/bash
lineItem5=61  valMin=260  valMax=433  

exptVals=( 257 261 265 269 273 277 281 285 289 293 297 \
           301 305 309 313 317 321 325 329 333 337 341 \
           345 349 353 357 361 365 369 373 377 381 385 \
           389 393 397 401 405 409 413 417 421 425 429 \
           433 )

for    v   in $( printf '%3.0f\n' {0..9}{0..9}{0,3,5,7} )
do     (( v>=valMin && v<=valMax )) && allVals+=( "$v" )
done

sortVals=( $(printf '%s\n' "${allVals[@]}" "${exptVals[@]}"|sort -nu) )
printf '%s ' "${sortVals[@]}"
```

---

Here we get to the core of your question. How to:

> remove the value ##7 if the sequence ##7 ##8 is encountered

The usual wisdom to do this is to call `sed`. Something like:

```
printf '%s ' "${sortVals[@]}" | sed -e 's/\(..7 \)\(..8\)/\2/g'
```

That will convert `..7 ..8` to `..8` (the backreference \2).

Then, you may add more filters for more changes. Something similar to:

```
printf '%s ' "${sortVals[@]}"          |
    sed -e 's/\(..7 \)\(..8\)/\2/g'    |
    sed -e 's/\(..\)3\( ..4\)/\12\2/g' 
echo
```

That will solve the `..7 ..8` to `..8` and the `..3 ..4` to `..2 ..4` items.

But your requirement of:

> but only if the ##3 or ##7 value is not found in my list

Is more complex to meet. We need to scan all the values with grep, and execute different code for each option. One usual solution is to use grep:

```
if printf '%s ' "${sortVals[@]}" | grep -Eq '..3|..7'; then
        cmd2=(cat)
else
        cmd2=(sed -e 's/\(..2\)\( ..3\)/\1/g')
fi
```

But that means to scan all values with grep for each condition.
The command created: `cmd2` is an array and may be used as this:

```
printf '%s ' "${sortVals[@]}"          |
    sed -e 's/\(..7 \)\(..8\)/\2/g'    |  "${cmd2[@]}"  | 
    sed -e 's/\(..\)3\( ..4\)/\12\2/g' |  "${cmd4[@]}"
echo
```

---

#### No grep

The values you are testing are only the last digit, which could be easily extracted with a modulo 10 math operation. And to make easier/faster 
the testing of values, we can create an array of indexes like this:

```
unset indexVals; declare -A indexVals
for v in "${sortVals[@]}"; do  indexVals[$((v%10))]=1; done
```

That's only one scan of values, no external tool called, and a big simplification of the testing of values (for example, for `..2` or `..3`):

```
(( ${indexVals[2]-0} || ${indexVals[3]-0} ))
```

---

An script with all the changes is:

```
#!/bin/bash
lineItem5=61  valMin=260  valMax=433  

exptVals=( 257 261 265 269 273 277 281 285 289 293 297 \
           301 305 309 313 317 321 325 329 333 337 341 \
           345 349 353 357 361 365 369 373 377 381 385 \
           389 393 397 401 405 409 413 417 421 425 429 \
           433 )

for    v   in $( printf '%3.0f\n' {0..9}{0..9}{0,3,5,7} )
do     (( v>=valMin && v<=valMax )) && allVals+=( "$v" )
done

sortVals=( $(printf '%s\n' "${allVals[@]}" "${exptVals[@]}" | sort -nu) )

unset indexVals; declare -A indexVals
for v in "${sortVals[@]}"; do  indexVals[$((v%10))]=1; done

cmd1=( sed -e 's/\(..7 \)\(..8\)/\2/g' )

(( ${indexVals[2]-0} || ${indexVals[3]-0} )) &&
    cmd2=( cat ) ||
    cmd2=( sed -e 's/\(..2\)\( ..3\)/\1/g' )

cmd3=( sed -e 's/\(..\)3\( ..4\)/\12\2/g' )

(( ${indexVals[3]-0} || ${indexVals[7]-0} )) &&
    cmd4=( cat ) ||
    cmd4=( sed -e 's/\(..6 ..\)7/\18/g' )

printf '%s ' "${sortVals[@]}" | "${cmd1[@]}" | "${cmd2[@]}" | 
                                "${cmd3[@]}" | "${cmd4[@]}" ; echo
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of generating the numbers by pattern, why not use `awk` to generate numbers as a numerical sequence?

for example,

```
$ awk -v from=100 -v to=200 -v ORS=' ' 'BEGIN{for(i=from;i<=to-10;i+=10)
                                 print i,i+3,i+5,i+7; ORS="\n"; print""}'
```

> 100 103 105 107 110 113 115 117 120 123 125 127 130 133 135 137 140 143 145 147 150 153 155 157 160 163 165 167 170 173 175 177 180
>   183 185 187 190 193 195 197

Comment: Sure, but how to inject in the external array and conditionally replace (or delete) certain consecutive values if the targeted value in the pair is not in the array.  To give one example I mention above, if the experimental array contains `116` I want to replace `117` in the algorithmically generated sequence with `118` ... but only if `117` does not also occur in the values from the experimental array as well.  Likewise if I have `108` in the experimental sequence, I want to delete `107` algorithmically generated sequence, but only if it does not occur in the experimental array.

Comment: In that case better to start with the initial sequence and fill in the details.  Can you give a small range example for range (100-200) experimental array and what do you expect as the final sequence.

Comment: if `expt=( 104 108 116 120 121 123 134 142 )` and range is `[100,158]` then the desired output would be `100 102 104 105 108 110 113 115 116 118 120 121 123 125 127 130 132 134 135 137 140 142 145 147 150 153 155 157`

Comment: This seems to work for the question itself:
`expt=( 104 108 116 120 121 123 134 142 ); printf '%s\n' ${expt[@]} $( awk -v from=100 -v to=200 -v ORS=' ' 'BEGIN{for(i=from;i<=to-10;i+=10) print i,i+3,i+5,i+7; ORS="\n"; print""}' ) | sort -n | tr '\n' '_' | sed -e 's#\([0-9]*2\)_[0-9]*3#\1#g' | sed -e 's#[0-9]*7_\([0-9]*8\)#\1#g' | sed -e 's#\([0-9]*0\)_\([0-9]*\)3_\([0-9]*4\)#\1_\22_\3#g' | sed -e 's#\([0-9]*6\)_\([0-9]*\)7_\([0-9]*0\)#\1_\28_\3#g'| tr '_' '\n' | sort -nr | uniq; unset expt;` seems to be working... not sure if this is the best way to do it though.

Comment: I feel that there is a hidden simpler pattern but too late for me to think about it clearly.  With mod 10, working in ranges between 1-5 and 6-0 it should be easier to modify the mid values.